# how to post multiple value with same key in python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
requests.post(url, data={'interests':'football','interests':'basketball'})
```

I tried this, but it is not working. How would I post `football` and `basketball` in the `interests` field?

Comment: Take a [lookie](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Dictionary keys *must* be unique, you can't repeat them. You'd use a sequence of key-value tuples instead, and pass this to `data`:

```
requests.post(url, data=[('interests', 'football'), ('interests', 'basketball')])
```

Alternatively, make the values of the `data` dictionary *lists*; each value in the list is used as a separate parameter entry:

```
requests.post(url, data={'interests': ['football', 'basketball']})
```

Demo POST to http://httpbin.org:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> r = requests.post(url, data=[('interests', 'football'), ('interests', 'basketball')])
>>> r.request.body
'interests=football&interests=basketball'
>>> r.json()['form']
{u'interests': [u'football', u'basketball']}
>>> r = requests.post(url, data={'interests': ['football', 'basketball']})
>>> r.request.body
'interests=football&interests=basketball'
>>> r.json()['form']
{u'interests': [u'football', u'basketball']}
```

Comment: @Bethlee: not sure why you'd ever do that. That's just being extra verbose, there is no advantage to using `files` here unless you __must__ send a multipart/form request, **and** you must strictly control the order of the fields **and** you have actual file data to send. Otherwise just use `data=(('worker_ids[]', '66'), ('worker_ids[]', '67'))`.

Comment: @Martjin: Yes. You're right. I know it's not a good way but In my case the server-side was wrongfully coded. I used the answer without any choice. I just want to share the other ways. Thank you for your advice. I will delete the comment

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to use `urllib3._collections.HTTPHeaderDict` as a dictionary that has multiple values under a key:

```
from urllib3._collections import HTTPHeaderDict
data = HTTPHeaderDict()
data.add('interests', 'football')
data.add('interests', 'basketball')
requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) directly:

> The data argument can also have multiple values for each key. This can
>   be done by making data either a list of tuples or a dictionary with
>   lists as values. This is particularly useful when the form has
>   multiple elements that use the same key:
>
> ```
> >>> payload_tuples = [('key1', 'value1'), ('key1', 'value2')]
> >>> r1 = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data=payload_tuples)
> >>> payload_dict = {'key1': ['value1', 'value2']}
> >>> r2 = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data=payload_dict)
> >>> print(r1.text)
> {
>   ...
>   "form": {
>     "key1": [
>       "value1",
>       "value2"
>     ]
>   },
>   ...
> }
> >>> r1.text == r2.text
> True
> ```

Comment: This one worked for me, and I could use it with the "files" function parameter .

Answer (score 1):

**curl** command string presents data as `-d 'product_ids[]=719&product_ids[]=107'`.
I was able to form the data array correctly by adding square brackets:

```
payload = [('product_ids[]', id) for id in ids_list]
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with curl.

Answer (score 0):

To post multiple values with the same key in Python requests, you need to use a list. For example, the following code will post the values football and basketball to the interests field:

```
import requests

url = "https://example.com/post"
data = {"interests": ["football", "basketball"]}

response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

This will result in the following POST request:

```
POST /post HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

interests=football&interests=basketball
```