# Sending an ASP.net POST with Python's Requests

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm scraping an old ASP.net website using Python's requests module.

I've spent 5+ hours trying to figure out how to simulate this POST request to no avail. Doing it the way I do it below, I essentially get a message saying "No item matches this item reference."

Any help would be deeply appreciated – here's the request and my code, a few things are modified out of respect to brevity and/or privacy:

**My own code:**

```
import requests

# Scraping the item number from the website, I have confirmed this is working.

#Then use the newly acquired item number to request the data.
item_url = http://www.example.com/EN/items/Pages/yourrates.aspx?vr= + item_number[0]
viewstate = r'/wEPD...' # Truncated for brevity.

# Create the appropriate request and payload.
payload = {"vr": int(item_number[0])}

item_request_body = {
        "__SPSCEditMenu": "true",
        "MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource": "",
        "MSOTlPn_SelectedWpId": "",
        "MSOTlPn_View": 0,
        "MSOTlPn_ShowSettings": "False",
        "MSOGallery_SelectedLibrary": "",
        "MSOGallery_FilterString": "",
        "MSOTlPn_Button": "none",
        "__EVENTTARGET": "",
        "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
        "MSOAuthoringConsole_FormContext": "",
        "MSOAC_EditDuringWorkflow": "",
        "MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName": "Browse",
        "MSOWebPartPage_Shared": "",
        "MSOLayout_LayoutChanges": "",
        "MSOLayout_InDesignMode": "",
        "MSOSPWebPartManager_OldDisplayModeName": "Browse",
        "MSOSPWebPartManager_StartWebPartEditingName": "false",
        "__VIEWSTATE": viewstate,
        "keywords": "Search our site",
        "__CALLBACKID": "ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_dbb9e9c7_fe1d_46df_8789_99a6c9db4b22",
        "__CALLBACKPARAM": "startvr"
    }

# Write the appropriate headers for the property information.
item_request_headers = {
    "Host": home_site,
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": len(encoded_valuation_request),
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Origin": home_site,
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Cookie": "__utma=48409910.1174413745.1405662151.1406402487.1406407024.17; __utmb=48409910.7.10.1406407024; __utmc=48409910; __utmz=48409910.1406178827.13.3.utmcsr=ratesandvallandingpage|utmccn=landingpages|utmcmd=button",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Referer": valuation_url,
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8"
}

    response = requests.post(url=item_url, params=payload, data=item_request_body, headers=item_request_headers)
    print response.text
```

**What Chrome is telling me the request looks like:**

```
Remote Address:202.55.96.131:80
Request URL:http://www.example.com/EN/items/Pages/yourrates.aspx?vr=123456789
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:21501
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:__utma=48409910.1174413745.1405662151.1406402487.1406407024.17; __utmb=48409910.7.10.1406407024; __utmc=48409910; __utmz=48409910.1406178827.13.3.utmcsr=ratesandvallandingpage|utmccn=landingpages|utmcmd=button
Host:www.site.com
Origin:www.site.com
Referer:http://www.example.com/EN/items/Pages/yourrates.aspx?vr=123456789
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36

Query String Parameters
vr:123456789

Form Data
__SPSCEditMenu:true
MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource:
MSOTlPn_SelectedWpId:
MSOTlPn_View:0
MSOTlPn_ShowSettings:False
MSOGallery_SelectedLibrary:
MSOGallery_FilterString:
MSOTlPn_Button:none
__EVENTTARGET:
__EVENTARGUMENT:
MSOAuthoringConsole_FormContext:
MSOAC_EditDuringWorkflow:
MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName:Browse
MSOWebPartPage_Shared:
MSOLayout_LayoutChanges:
MSOLayout_InDesignMode:
MSOSPWebPartManager_OldDisplayModeName:Browse
MSOSPWebPartManager_StartWebPartEditingName:false
__VIEWSTATE:/wEPD...(Omitted for length)
keywords:Search our site
__CALLBACKID:ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_dbb9e9c7_fe1d_46df_8789_99a6c9db4b22
__CALLBACKPARAM:startvr
```

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I think your `item_url` is currently mal-constructed, its not a string.

Comment: Oh yeah for sure - didn't notice that, but that wasn't my problem, it's because I was reformatting things to exclude the actual URLs :) Thanks for the spot though!

Comment: `Event` and `ViewState` validation, in addition to mentioned (in answer below) possible `session` are all possibilities....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have too many request parameters, and should *not* set the content-type, content-length, host, origin, or connection headers; *leave those to `requests` to set*.

You are also doubling up the url parameters; either add the `vr` parameter to the URL manually *or* use `params`, not do both.

It may well be that some of the parameters in the POST body are generated by the ASP application tied to a session. I'd use a GET request with a [Session object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) the `valuation_url`, parse the form in that page to extract the `__CALLBACKID` parameter. The requests Session will then store any cookies the server sets and reuse those:

```
item_request_headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8"
}
payload = {"vr": int(item_number[0])}

session = requests.Session(headers=item_request_headers)

# Get form page
form_response = session.get(validation_url, params=payload) 

# parse form page; BeautifulSoup could do this for example
soup = BeautifulSoup(form_response.content)
callbackid = soup.select('input[name=__CALLBACKID]')[0]['value']

item_request_body = {
    "__SPSCEditMenu": "true",
    "MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource": "",
    "MSOTlPn_SelectedWpId": "",
    "MSOTlPn_View": 0,
    "MSOTlPn_ShowSettings": "False",
    "MSOGallery_SelectedLibrary": "",
    "MSOGallery_FilterString": "",
    "MSOTlPn_Button": "none",
    "__EVENTTARGET": "",
    "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
    "MSOAuthoringConsole_FormContext": "",
    "MSOAC_EditDuringWorkflow": "",
    "MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName": "Browse",
    "MSOWebPartPage_Shared": "",
    "MSOLayout_LayoutChanges": "",
    "MSOLayout_InDesignMode": "",
    "MSOSPWebPartManager_OldDisplayModeName": "Browse",
    "MSOSPWebPartManager_StartWebPartEditingName": "false",
    "__VIEWSTATE": viewstate,
    "keywords": "Search our site",
    "__CALLBACKID": callbackid,
    "__CALLBACKPARAM": "startvr"
}

item_url = 'http://www.example.com/EN/items/Pages/yourrates.aspx'

response = session.post(url=item_url, params=payload, data=item_request_body,
                        headers={'Referer': form_response.url})
```

The session handles the headers (setting a user agent, and accept parameters), only on the POST with the session do we add a referrer header as well.

Comment: Super helpful, Martijn, thank you! I'm still working through things, but as soon as I finish implementing and testing the solution I will be sure to confirm :)

Comment: Also, do you know the way in which I would encode this type of thing? `__CALLBACKID=ctl00%24SPWebPartManager1%24g_dbb9e9c7_fe1d_46df_8789_99a6c9db4b22` It gave me an error in the callback, presumably due to the unusual percent signs.

Comment: Include the *decoded* value; leave encoding to `requests`.  `%24` is an encoded `$` for example.

Comment: You are so helpful Martijn! Thanks again! Works well, now I just need to automate retrieving a few of the bits of information via BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @DavidK.: you can combine `requests` and BeautifulSoup with [`robobrowser`](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/); it'll help you fill in the forms too.

Comment: Good idea, but I'm trying to do it purely with HTTP requests, no browser layer. I need maximal speed for a sizable dataset, and none of the browsers I've tried are fast enough. However, if you've had good experiences with robobrowser I may have to try it!

Comment: @DavidK.: `robobrowser` is **not** a browser layer. It is `requests` plus BeautifulSoup plus a little glue to handle forms.

Comment: Ah, well that sounds even better then! I'm just using bs4 and requests myself at the moment, but that may be a convenient package.

Answer (score 1):

Relevant to the question title, but not exactly the poster's situation -- I'd like to add one more useful tip to Martijn's answer that includes some general *requests* library advice for POST requests.

Examining a request payload on a browser (e.g. Chrome's Network tab in Developer Tools) may show that there are **multiples of certain keys/fields within the payload**.

**Chrome's Request Payload Example:**

```
...
"ctl00$cphMain$ctlInvoiceStatuses$lbInvoiceStatus": "AcceptedModified",
"ctl00$cphMain$ctlInvoiceStatuses$lbInvoiceStatus": "InvoiceFullyDisputed",
"ctl00$cphMain$ctlInvoiceStatuses$lbInvoiceStatus": "DisputedItemsClosed",
...
```

Copying the browser's request to match this exactly in your *requests*'s payload/data argument will NOT work (or at least not get you the results you expect... you'll still likely get a 200 status code response) -- it will only send the value for the LAST occurrence of the key/field.

***Requests* Data/Payload that will NOT work (or at least not get you the results you expect):**

```
payload = {
   ...
   "ctl00$cphMain$ctlInvoiceStatuses$lbInvoiceStatus": "AcceptedModified",
   "ctl00$cphMain$ctlInvoiceStatuses$lbInvoiceStatus": "InvoiceFullyDisputed",
   "ctl00$cphMain$ctlInvoiceStatuses$lbInvoiceStatus": "DisputedItemsClosed",
   ...
}
r = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Instead, you must put these multiple keys'/fields' values into a list:

***Requests* Data/Payload that WILL work (or get your the expected results):**

```
payload = {
   ...
   "ctl00$cphMain$ctlInvoiceStatuses$lbInvoiceStatus": ["AcceptedModified", "InvoiceFullyDisputed", "DisputedItemsClosed"],
   ...
}
r = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

...it took me a few hours to realize this, looking deeply into ASP.NET website mechanics thinking there was I needed to understand there.  Nope.  So, just trying to save someone some time, hopefully.

Thank you to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384230/how-to-post-multiple-value-with-same-key-in-python-requests) for helping me come to this realization.

NOTE:  You can check exactly what your sent payload looks like by looking at `r.request.body` on the response object (`r`, this case) after your request.  This is how I realized mine was missing some information (i.e. the multiple fields/keys).