# python requests - posting multiple values with same key, combined with regular keys

Tags: python, forms, python-requests

I need to reproduce the following POST form structure:
[image]

from what I found, I can represent multiple values of `sites` key this way: [how to post multiple value with same key in python requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384230/how-to-post-multiple-value-with-same-key-in-python-requests)

but how to combine this multi-valued key with regular keys `action` and `extype`? I can't use a regular dict for parameters anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you can't use a "regular dict". On the contrary:

```
params = {'sites[]': [951, 1007, ...], 'action': 'set', 'extype': 'exclude'}
requests.post('url', data=params)
```