# How to send the same header twice with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to send the same header parameter twice with python requests. is it possible?

When I try to do the following request, the Requests lib from python ignores one of the passed headers even sending it with different cases:

Example:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.example.com"

headers = {"test":"test1", 
           "Test":"test2"}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(req.request.headers)
```

Comment: As http headers are not case-sensitive, then no. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive#5259004

Comment: And anyway why would you want to do that?

Comment: I think what you're actually looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23384253/10987432)

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP header names are *not* case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive), so `requests` handles this correctly. That the keys in the dictionary are case-insensitive is also sometimes mentioned in `requests`' docs, like [`Session.headers`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Session.headers), [`Response.headers`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.headers)