# How can multiple "text" parameters be passed to the DeepL API using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, machine-translation, deepl

I am trying to pass multiple text variables with the DeepL API using Python 3's `requests` library, but as yet have been unable to pass multiple text parameters to a request. The [documentation](https://www.deepl.com/docs-api/translating-text/large-volumes/) states that "Up to 50 text parameters can be submitted in one request" but after trying to pass multiple text variables using `"&text":` and the regular `"text":` keys, the call only returns a single translation.

For reference, here is the code I used:

```
two_s = r.post(url="https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate", data={"target_lang": "EN", "auth_key": auth_key, "text": s2t1, "text":s2t2})
```

and

```
two_s = r.post(url="https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate", data={"target_lang": "EN", "auth_key": auth_key, "text": s2t1, "&text":s2t2})
```

Where auth_key is my authentication key, and `s2t1` and `s2t2` are different "strings 2 translate." How can multiple `"text":` parameters be passed to the DeepL API using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I attempted to pass s2t1 and s2t2 to `text` as a list of elements, as outlined in Martijn Pieters ([Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)) answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384230/how-to-post-multiple-value-with-same-key-in-python-requests) question and both strings were translated and returned by the server. Here is the code I used to make that request:

```
both_s = r.post(url="https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate", data={"target_lang": "EN", "auth_key": auth_key, "text": [s2t1,s2t2]})
```

Where `auth_key` is my DeepL authentication key.

Edit: It is also worth noting that DeepL has an ~5000 character limit that it can translate at a time, so while multiple strings can be passed to the text parameter, it is easier to simply pass the entire string along. I will do some efficiency analysis of passing a full 4800 character string in text and a test passing a split list of strings and update further.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a list of tuples as `data` attribute.
After some test with some echo services it seems to work with several values for the same "key".

```
r.post(
    url="https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate", 
    data=[
        ("target_lang", "EN"),
        ("auth_key", auth_key),
        ("text", s2t1),
        ("text", s2t2),
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think the method of passing a list of strings to `text` is a bit more simple, so I'm going to go ahead and accept that answer -- but thank you for your help!