# how to iterate a complete excel file

Tags: python

I have an excel file, which contains only one sheet, called 'Sheet1'. What I want to do is read all the rows from each column to send that data to a request in an API. I'm only able to send the last data of the worksheet, using this code:

```
my_table = pd.read_excel("Myexcel.xlsx")
      
for i, name in enumerate(my_table["Name"]):  
  categ = str(int(my_table.loc[i, "CategoryId"]))
  brd = my_table.loc[i, "BrandName"]
  des = my_table.loc[i, "Description"]
  titl = my_table.loc[i, "Title"]

payloads = {"Name": name, "CategoryId": categ, "BrandName": brd, "Description": des, "Title": titl}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payloads)
response = response.json()
```

What I want to do is send all the values. I couldn't specify how many lines there are, because the amount of data in the file can be changed, either more or less. I would like to do this in python

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are assigning `name`, `Category.id` .... `Title` to values associated with rows, and then not doing anything with them before reassigning the values again.
if the comments I'm reading [here] are to be believed, it seems you can make the elements of your payload lists, where the elements in the list are elements from your row/xlsx file.

Maybe try something like

```
my_table = pd.read_excel("Myexcel.xlsx")
      
for i, name in enumerate(my_table["Name"]):  
  categ.append(str(int(my_table.loc[i, "CategoryId"])))
  brd.append(my_table.loc[i, "BrandName"])
  des.append(my_table.loc[i, "Description"])
  titl.append(my_table.loc[i, "Title"])

payloads = {"Name": name, "CategoryId": categ, "BrandName": brd, "Description": des, "Title": titl}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payloads)
response = response.json()
```

Can't promise anything though, sorry! This is the route I would try, but I don't know if it will lead anywhere. I'm going to post another link that may contain helpful discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384230/how-to-post-multiple-value-with-same-key-in-python-requests)

Comment: I understood what you meant. but somehow I managed to send the values ​​I wanted to the api without adding the append. I didn't understand why.